# What is the correct sequence of loading a color scheme in your .vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I don't understand how to get the "correct" colors in terminal vim.  My `.vimrc` file looks like:

```
syntax enable
colorscheme desert256
```

I am doing this on a black background in Terminal in Mac OS X Lion.  But when I execute vim, I get the colors, but I notice that `set background=light` when it should be dark (vim always seems to guess wrong on the background).  So if I do a `set background=dark` the colors change but then if I type `colorscheme`, vim reports that I am back to default.

Should I be using `syntax on` or some other command?

Please provide some guidance on how to properly do syntax highlighting in terminal vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this snippet from `zenburn.vim`.

```
" * Work-around to a Vim bug, it seems to misinterpret ctermfg and 234 and 237            
"   as light values, and sets background to light for some people. If you have            
"   this problem, use:                                                                    

"   let g:zenburn_force_dark_Background = 1        

if exists("g:zenburn_force_dark_Background")
    " Force dark background, because of a bug in VIM:  VIM sets background
    " automatically during "hi Normal ctermfg=X"; it misinterprets the high
    " value (234 or 237 above) as a light color, and wrongly sets background to
    " light.  See ":help highlight" for details.
    set background=dark
endif
```

To fix this, just add

`set background=dark`

to the end of `desert256.vim` after all the highlighting.

Comment: ok, but if I do this, it still reports `default` as the color scheme (even though the colors *are* different than default) - Guess its ok as a workaround...

Comment: @JasonWaldrop Hmm, it returns `desert256` for me.